# View doesn't get visible when a method is called

Tags: android

I'm creating an image to PDF converter app. I want to show an indeterminate progress bar when a user clicks on a button. But, when I run the app, the progress bar doesn't get visible(which I had set invisible previously in its XML file). But, when I don't call convert method, it does get visible. That means something is wrong in the convert method but I can't figure out what's wrong in it. Convert method is the method in which the image to PDF conversion takes place.

Code of setting onClickListener to button.

```
conButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            try {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                convert();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Convert method's code:

```
private void convert() throws IOException {

        PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(getApplicationContext());

        document = new PDDocument();

        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(0f, 0f, getImageWidth(i), getImageHeight(i)));
            document.addPage(page);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream;
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

            try {
                // Define a content stream for adding to the PDF
                contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

                Image image = images.get(i);
                Uri imageUri = image.getUri();
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0, 0, 0);
                contentStream.setFont(font, 20);
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(getImageWidth(i) - 270, 15);
                contentStream.showText("Created using Pidify app");
                contentStream.endText();


                PDImageXObject ximage = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(document, bitmap);
                contentStream.drawImage(ximage, 60f, 60f);


                // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
                contentStream.close();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Activity", "Exception thrown while creating PDF", e);
            }
        }


        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pidify");
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        // Save the final pdf document to a file
        String userInputName = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (userInputName.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please put a valid PDF file name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            File saveFile= new File(path+"/"+userInputName+".pdf");
            document.save(saveFile);
            Toast.makeText(this, "PDF saved to the location: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Successfully saved");
        document.close();

    }
```

Info I get in logcat:

```
2021-07-14 20:45:38.247 18407-18407/com.example.hijiki I/Choreographer: Skipped 622 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Can You show the stack trace if any exception occurs?

Comment: Could you describe the problem a little bit more? What happens when you open the app without tapping the button? Is is spinning? What happens when you tap the button? And what happens after the conversion? Post some errors from log cat to help us to find the problem.

Comment: @sweak and Skizo, thank you, I checked the logs and found out that app was doing too much work on main thread. That was causing the problem.